# como colocar isso aqui na ordem crescente?

Tags: php, array, order

```
<?php
  $var = 5;
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $var-1; $i++) {
    $new_data = array($i => $count[$i]["rank"]);
    foreach ($new_data as $i => $key) {
      print(var_export($key).",");
    }
  }
?>
```

ele retorna isso: **87,41,88,32,26,26,48,16,0,34,46,135,11,38,52,33,**

como retornar isso em ordem crescente? ou na ordem numérica?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Ao invés de ficar poluindo o site com perguntas repetidas, busque ler os comentários da pergunta original e seguir as dicas dadas.

Comment: Willian, tudo bem, acredito por ser novo no site está tendo dificuldades, mas, um coisa sobre as perguntas, não precisa repetir a mesma pergunta várias vezes, faça uma vez só que logo alguém pode indicar um duplicada que responderá a sua pergunta ou até mesmo um resposta. Como você já fez uma pergunta parecida (que aqui é chamado duplicata) essa com certeza será fechada apesar que agora já tem uma resposta que pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Coloque isto antes do `foreach`

```
sort($new_data, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

[Referência (PHP4, 5 e7): PHP Sort](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação abaixo tem varias opções para fazer isso, mas uma delas é a `asort`

```
<?php
$frutas = array("d" => "limao", "a" => "laranja", "b" => "banana", "c" => "melancia");
asort($frutas);
foreach( $frutas as $chave => $valor ){
    echo "$chave = $valor\n";
}
?>
```

**Vai imprimir:**

```
b = banana
a = laranja
d = limao
c = melancia
```

O seu é array numérico, mas deve servir

Documentação Oficial: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php